# Separate usernames by "," or "and" in string depending on number of users

Tags: php, string, loops, foreach, while-loop

```
$playernothing = 0;
$sortdrawmax = max($p1count,$player2count,$player3count,$player4count,$player5count,$player6count,$player7count);
$sortdraww = mysql_query("SELECT username,count FROM blackjackmultijoin WHERE gameid = '$gameid' AND count = '$sortdrawmax'");
while($sortdraw = mysql_fetch_array($sortdraww)){
$playernothing++;
$playersname.$playernothing = $sortdraw['username'];
}

if($sortdrawmax < 1){ 
   $drawoutcome = "All users <b>busted</b> and the game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
}
elseif($playernothing == 2){ 
   $drawoutcome = "$playersname1 and $playersname2 drew with <b>$sortdrawmax</b>! Game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
 }
elseif($playernothing == 3){ 
   $drawoutcome = "$playersname1, $playersname2 and $playersname3 drew with <b>$sortdrawmax</b>! Game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
}
```

I have the above code in a part of my Multiplayer Blackjack script.
My intentions is a code that will complete the `$drawoutcome` above so that for each user which has the highest amount in a draw are seperated by a comma with the last name coming after "and".

Can anyone please help with the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$playernothing = 0;
$sortdrawmax = max($p1count,$player2count,$player3count,$player4count,$player5count,$player6count,$player7count);
$sortdraww = mysql_query("SELECT username,count FROM blackjackmultijoin WHERE gameid = '$gameid' AND count = '$sortdrawmax'");
while($sortdraw = mysql_fetch_array($sortdraww))
{
    $playernothing++;
    $arr[] = $playersname.$playernothing = $sortdraw['username'];
}
if(count($arr) > 1)
{
    $last = $arr[count($arr)-1];
    unset($arr[count($arr)-1]);
    $usernames = implode(",", $arr)." and {$last}";
}
else
    $usernames = implode("", $arr);
if($sortdrawmax < 1)
{ 
   $drawoutcome = "All users <b>busted</b> and the game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
}
elseif($playernothing == 2)
{ 
   $drawoutcome = "$usernames drew with <b>$sortdrawmax</b>! Game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
}
elseif($playernothing == 3)
{ 
   $drawoutcome = "$usernames drew with <b>$sortdrawmax</b>! Game will restart in <b>$gamedrawleft</b> seconds..."; 
}
```

Comment: With a couple of small changes worked a treat! Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

First, put the names into an array, instead of individual variables. Once you have the complete list of players, use array_pop to remove the last player from the array (and set it into a variable). Finally, use implode to join the rest of the list, with a string concat at the end.

Presuming you already have the array of players ($player_list):

```
$last_player = array_pop($player_list);
$draw_outcome = implode(', ', $player_list) . ' and ' . $last_player;
```

This code would require handling the special case of less than 2 players, but otherwise it should be good.

Comment: Would I do the array for users in the while loop or in a normal fetch query?

Comment: You should check if it’s not just one user.